# Creating a table using mysql, jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have made connections and statement in my java program.  When i try to execute the below statement it throws me and error

```
String details;
details="create table details(ID INTEGER,Name VARCHAR(255),Department VARCHAR(255))";
st.executeUpdate(details);
```

error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'details(a INTEGER,name VARCHAR(255),id INTERGER)' 
at line 1
```

Explain how to solve the error?

Comment: use the staement as : **create table \`details\`(\`ID\` INTEGER,\`Name\` VARCHAR(255),\`Department\` VARCHAR(255))**

Comment: your error and your code doesn't match

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't appear to correspond to the error message. The problem with the error message code is the spelling mistake INTERGER rather than INTEGER.

I tested your code & it runs fine & then replaced it with the code from the error message with spelling corrected & that ran OK too from MySQL workbench.

```
create table details(a INTEGER,name VARCHAR(255),id INTEGER);
```